# Having trouble doing a "where" in a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

For example, I have `Users`, `Roles` and a many to many table called `user_role`. I want to do something like `User::with('roles')->where('role', '=', 'admin')->get()`. However it's not recognizing 'role' field in the `Roles` table. How can I achieve a `where` clause on not the intermediate table but the other joining one?

How my many-to-many relationship is defined:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the patient folks at `laravel.io`:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function($query)
{
  $query->where('role', '=', 'admin');
})->get();
```